# Google street view camera parameters

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am trying to reproduce the google street view camera in my rendering software.
But I think that some parameters are missing because the result has a problem (scale or field of view distorsion ?).
What I know :
 - camera position : I set it (latitude/longitude).
 - horizontal fov + pitch + heading : given by google API.

But the real focal length is missing i.e. the **sensor size** or the **crop factor** or the **focal length mutiplier**. (different words for the same thing I think).
Do you know if google provide this parameter ?
If not did somebody find a good approximation ?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean the zoom? i.e. `panorama.getZoom()`

Comment: No : the zoom gives the fov in the api. Search "crop factor" in google.

Comment: Google Maps API documentation tells you the information it provides, if it's not in the documentation, then they don't provide it - and in your case it looks like they don't: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewPanorama

Comment: Thanks Adam for your answers. Yes it is not in the API but I hoped that the information can be in articles describing the google car equipment for example. I searched a lot on the web but I found nothing... So I will have to estimate the equivalent focal length.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? http://davidpapp.com/2014/04/27/specs-of-a-google-street-view-car/ I'm looking for the information also. Based on what we see here, it looks like its 5.1mm focal length.