# Google Street View Internal Camera Parameters

Tags: google-maps, camera, google-street-view

Does anyone know what camera google street view uses for capturing the images? Specifically, I am looking for the camera internal parameters (viz. focal lengths and image center location and skew) link:[camera intrinsic parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning#Intrinsic_parameters).

I am aware of this question [Google street view camera parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976557/google-street-view-camera-parameters). It says the API does not provide the internal parameters.

Comment: Closest you can get: http://www.google.com/maps/about/behind-the-scenes/streetview/

Comment: still does not really talk the the camera intrinsic parameters or the make of the camera.

Comment: I doubt that information is available to public. If it were, most likely it would be in the link I gave you.